# selecting data from two different columns in one table that point to the same column in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables which i have summarised below just to keep the question simple.

The first table has a list of tasks - the two important columns to note is the id number "idTask" and the name of that task "sgItemName". It looks like this

| idTask | sgItemName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Do this |
| 2 | Do that |
| 3 | Then this |
| 4 | Then that |

The second table lists each task that has a precedent task that needs to be completed before it, and then what that precedent is - the two important columns to note is the parent task "fkidParentTask" and the precedent task "fkidPrecedentTask". Some tasks might have multiple precedents. It looks like this

| fkidParentTask | fkidPrecedentTask |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |

What i would like to achieve is a select query that gives me an output as follows

| Parent Task | Precedent Task |
| --- | --- |
| Do that | Do this |
| Then this | Do that |
| Then this | Do this |
| Then that | Then this |
| Then that | Do that |

I'm still learning SQL but I cannot get this to work at all! Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL-Server:

```
   Select tm1.sgItemName as [Parent Task] , tm2.sgItemName [Precedent Task]
    from ParentPrecedentMapping ppm
    join Taskmaster tm1 on ppm.fkidParenttask = tm1.idtask
    join Taskmaster tm2 on ppm.fkidPrecedenttask = tm2.idtask
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `table1` multiple times in the join as follows:

```
select t11.sgItemName as ParentTask,
       t12.sgItemName as PrecedentTask
  from table2 t2 
  join table1 t11 on t2.fkidParentTask = t1.idTask
  join table1 t12 on t2.fkidPrecedentTask = t1.idTask
```